# Visio Gantt Calendar related to Fiscal Calendar

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013

Can I change the Visio Gantt calendar to a Fiscal calendar? I looked at Gantt Chart Options and could not find anything. For instance Q1 starts Oct 1 not Jan 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what Visio version you are currently using, perhaps the Gantt Chart Frame (Visio 2013 Professional version, has Time units that can be setup for Quarters and Months - make sure the timescale start date is setup for Jan 1  - if that's what you need.